# Change font family of tinymce content

Tags: tinymce, font-family

I want to change the font family of my TinyMCE content.
I tried:

```
tinymce.get('myid').execCommand("fontName", false, "Verdana");
```

But this is actually only changing the font in the menu. My content is still written in Arial.
How could I proceed to change the font family of the text already present in the TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on how the content gets its font setting.  If there are inline styles on the content you would have to parse the HTML and remove/modify the inline styles to use the font you wish to use.

If there are no inline styles the content would rely on CSS to control the styles so you would either use the `content_css` setting in your TinyMCE configuration to set the CSS defaults you want or inject inline styles to override the CSS.